# How to edit Freestyle SVG exporter

Tags: rendering, freestyle

I want to export a 2D DXF file including hidden lines.

I can set up 2 linetypes, "visible" and "hidden" and run the render.

I then open the svg file using Inkscape and saveas a DXF file.

However, both linetypes are allocated the same layer: "strokes".

I want the "hidden" linetype to be on a different layer. Is this possible?

Also, I would like to look at exporting the paths directly to DXF. Which Python scripts would I need to edit to do this? I'm not even sure it's within my capabilities, but would like to look at the code.

Comment: Even though the question is quite interesting, the way it's currenty written makes it a litte bit out of topic. The SVG produced by the Blender SVG exporter preserves the layers, they get lost in the DXF conversion. I would suggest to edit the question focusing on the last part. BTW, converting the SVG exporter to a DXF exporter sounds not an easy task!

Comment: why not ask the [dev (Folkert de Vries) directly](https://github.com/folkertdev/freestyle-svg-exporter/issues) if he can add a mode to put certain lines types on different layers / group-elements. Or express interest in that being a feature.

Comment: Thank you both. So it's not a blender problem, it's the way Inkscape does the conversion? Makes sense I suppose. @Zeffi, I have taken your advice and posted a request on the project Github issues board. Thanks again, Dave

Comment: if you are really stuck perhaps you can save out two svgs, and convert them to two separate dxf and merge them in something like AutoCAD or DraftSight

Comment: Yes, that's how I was doing it before. I think my best solution is to write something quick and dirty in C or perhaps in Perl to take the SVG file and convert it directly to DXF. As Carlo suggests, the information is present in the SVG XML file, it should be easy enough to generate a DXF file from it.